# Dice rolling program with counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, dice

I'm new to programming and I have a task that I can't figure out on my own.

The task is to make a program that let's you decide how many dices to throw, 1 to 5, with checking if you make a wrong input.
After every roll the number of the die will show and the total so far.
If the die rolls a 6 then it is not included in the total and you get to more rolls. This is where I'm stuck. I want my program to restart the loop if the die turns a 6 and just ad 2 rolls to the sumDices and continue the loop, but I can't get it to work.

here is my code:

```
import random
numDices=0
total = 0
print("------------")
print("DICE ROLLING")
print("------------")
print()
exit=False
reset=False
while True:
    while True:
        numDices=int(input("How many dices to throw? (1-5) "))
        if numDices<1 or numDices>5:
            print("Wrong input, try again")
            break
        while True:
            if reset==True:
                break
            for i in range(numDices):
                dicesArray = list(range(numDices))
                dicesArray[i] = random.randint(1, 6)
                print(dicesArray[i])
                total += dicesArray[i]
                if dicesArray[i] == 1:
                    print("You rolled a one, the total is: ",str(total))
                elif dicesArray[i] == 2:
                    print("You rolled a two, the total is: ",str(total))
                elif dicesArray[i] == 3:
                    print("You rolled a three, the total is: ",str(total))
                elif dicesArray[i] == 4:
                    print("You rolled a four, the total is: ",str(total))
                elif dicesArray[i] == 5:
                    print("You rolled a five, the total is: ",str(total))
                elif dicesArray[i] == 6:
                    total-=6
                    numDices+=2
                    print("You rolled a six, rolling two new dices")
                    reset=True
        print("The total sum is",str(total),"with",numDices,"number of rolls.")
        print()
        restart=(input("Do you want to restart press Enter, to quit press 9. "))
        if restart=="9":
            exit=True
            break
        else:
            print()
            break
    if exit==True:
        break
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, the problem is if the die rolls a six, it doesn't roll two more times, it just ads to the sum and subtracts from the total, without rolling two more times. If the die rolls a six, it needs to roll two more times, plus the original amout of rolls. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Why line 35 `total-=6`?

Comment: Because if the die rolls a six, that should not be counted to the total, but ads two more rolls. The new rolls should be added to the total, unless one of them is a six, then the re-rolling countinus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it the following way, slightly modifying your code, counting the available dices. I reduced the nested loops there too

```
import random
numDices=0
total = 0
print("------------")
print("DICE ROLLING")
print("------------")
print()
start = True
while start:
    numDices=int(input("How many dices to throw? (1-5) "))
    if numDices<1 or numDices>5:
        print("Wrong input, try again")
        break
    total = 0
    dices_counter = 0
    while numDices > 0 :
        eyes = random.randint(1, 6)
        dices_counter+=1 
        total += eyes
        if eyes == 1:
            print("You rolled a one, the total is: ",str(total))
            numDices-=1
        elif eyes == 2:
            print("You rolled a two, the total is: ",str(total))
            numDices-=1
        elif eyes == 3:
            print("You rolled a three, the total is: ",str(total))
            numDices-=1
        elif eyes == 4:
            print("You rolled a four, the total is: ",str(total))
            numDices-=1
        elif eyes == 5:
            print("You rolled a five, the total is: ",str(total))
            numDices-=1
        elif eyes == 6:
            total-=6
            numDices+=2
            print("You rolled a six, rolling two new dices")
    print("The total sum is",str(total),"with",dices_counter,"number of rolls.")
    print()
    start=(input("Do you want to restart press Enter, to quit press 9. "))
    if start=="9":
        break
    else:
        print()
        start = True
```

Comment: Thank you, great assistance!

Comment: Glad it helped. If an answer solved your question you can mark the related answer with the gray checkmark on the left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem I would replace your current for loop with a while loop

Moreover, I see a lot of unacessary things in your code, I will try to list them :

- Why do you use so many "while True"?
- Why don't you just use exit()    function to exit instead of using a
  variable?
- Is all the if part    really necessary, can't you just print the
  number?

Here's my proposal:

```
import random
remaining_dices=0
total = 0
print("------------")
print("DICE ROLLING")
print("------------")
print()

while True:
    remaining_dices=int(input("How many dices to throw? (1-5) "))
    if remaining_dices<1 or remaining_dices>5:
        print("Wrong input, try again")
        break
    dicesArray = list()
    while remaining_dices>0:
        dice_value = random.randint(1, 6)
        dicesArray.append(dice_value)
        print(dice_value)
        total += dice_value
        remaining_dices -= 1
        if(dice_value == 6):
            total-=6
            remaining_dices +=2
            print("You rolled a 6, rolling two new dices")
        else:
            print("You rolled a " + str(dice_value) + ", the total is : " +str(total))

    restart=(input("Do you want to restart press Enter, to quit press 9. "))
    if restart=="9":
        exit()
    else:
        print()
```

Comment: Very VERY new to programming and havn't had alot of good teaching. Really appreciate your input. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(numDices):
```

Your for loop limits the number of iterations as soon as `range(numDices)` is evaluated/executed.  When you attempt to increase the number of iterations with `numDices+=2` it does not have any effect because `range(numDices)` is only evaluated once.

If you want to be able to change the number of iterations, use another while loop and use `i` as a counter.  Something like.

```
i = 0
while i <= numDices:
    ...
    ...
    if ...:
        ...
    elif ...:
    ...
    i += 1
```

Then in the suite for `elif dicesArray[i] == 6:` the statement `numDices += 2` will effectively increase the number of iterations.

---

I see another problem that you haven't mentioned. You start with a fixed length list based on the original value of `numDices` and you use `i` as an index for that list.

```
dicesArray = list(range(numDices))`
...
dicesArray[i]
...
```

If `i` can potentially be greater than the **original** `numDices` (greater than `len(dicesArray)`) you will eventually get an IndexError.  You should probably start with an empty list and append to it. To *get* the most recent dice roll use  `dicesArray[-1]` instead of `dicesArray[i]`.

```
...
dicesArray = []
i = 0
while i <= numDices:
    dicesArray.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    total += dicesArray[-1]
    if dicesArray[-1] == 1:
        ...
    ...
```

---

[6.3.2. Subscriptions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions)

Comment: Wow, really pedagogical help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive function

```
import random

total = 0
diceRollList = []

# Define dice rolling function
def rollDice():
    rollResult = random.randint(1, 6)
    if rollResult == 6:
        # If 6 Rolled run two more rolls and sum the results
        print("Rolled a 6 Rolling 2 more")
        return sum([rollDice() for _ in range(2)])
    # If 6 not rolled return the result
    print(f"Rolled a {rollResult}")
    return rollResult

while True:

    numberOfDice = int(input("How many Die to throw: "))

    if numberOfDice not in range(1, 6):
        print("Number of dice should be between 1 and 5")
        break

    for dice in range(numberOfDice):
        print(f"Rolling Dice {dice}")
        # Add result to the total
        total += rollDice()
        print(f"Running Total: {total}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This one tracks how many it has rolled:

```
import random

a = int(0)
b = int(0)
c = int(0)
d = int(0)
e = int(0)
f = int(0)
limit = 101
count = 0

while True:
    g = (random.randint(1, 6))
    print(g)
    count += 1
    if g == 1:
        a += 1
    elif g == 2:
        b += 1
    elif g == 3:
        c += 1
    elif g == 4:
        d += 1
    elif g == 5:
        e += 1
    elif g == 6:
        f += 1
    if count > limit:
        break

print(f"There are {a} 1's")
print(f"There are {b} 2's")
print(f"There are {c} 3's")
print(f"There are {d} 4's")
print(f"There are {e} 5's")
print(f"There are {f} 6's")
```

Comment: `int(0) == 0` in Python

Comment: Also why use a `while` loop that requires you to maintain the `count` variable and `break`? Why not just `for _ in range(limit):`?